# FIX Protocol: Receiving out of Sequence Message during retransmission causes loop in retransmission

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixn

I have a fix client using QuickFIX/n as the FIX layer.

If for some technical reason my client gets disconnected, the FIX server will continue sending messages until it notices the client is no more present (with heartbeat I assume).

When my client reconnects it will notice the gap on first message. For instance if my client last received message has SeqNuM=124 and upon reconnection the server sends SeqNum=152, it means the server sent messages from 125 to 151 before being aware of the disconnect.

My issue happens afterwards. My client sends a Resend request 34=2 with BeginSeqNo 7=125 and EndSeqNo=0 (give me everything). During this retransmission and before it finishes, the FIX server sends me new message with SeqNo=153

So what my clients get is:

```
- Disconnects with last message 124
- Reconnects 
- Receive 151
- Ask for Resend from 125 to 0 (everything after 125)
- Receive 125
- Receive 126
- Receive 127
- Receive 152 (35=8) <-- this makes the retransmission abort on my side
- Ask For resend from 128 to 0
---> if the number of message to resend is too high and new messages keep coming in
     my client never manages to get the full retransmission in one go.
```

When talking with the other party (responsible for the server), they say it's OK to continue sending new messages during retransmission and that I should cache them until retransmission is finished.

It seems like it's not the way QuickFIX/n implemented this (I found no option to handle this specific case) but when looking at FIX documentation I can't find any info about this cache procedure. I assume also that this cache procedure is quite complex as I should probably cache for a given time (otherwise I may wait forever for missing messages).

My question is simple:
What is this cache procedure and where can I find specs about it? And, is this handled by QuickFIX libraries or should I implement something specific on top of it?

Comment: I am not that familiar with QuickFIX/n, but did you make sure to use the most recent version?

Comment: Unfortunatly QuickFix/N releases are not that great. I'm using 1.8.0 version (from 2018-01-31). There is a new release 1.9.0 (2019-10-31) but this release ha not been released to Nuget. Even release 1.8.0 on nuget is unofficial. I did check all issues (open and closed) on the github and did not find anything related to this anyway.

Comment: First I need confirmation that people doing FIX are doing what my third party is telling me to do.

Comment: What is message 152 in your example? Is it a SequenceReset message or a normal app message?

Comment: It's a normal app message 35=8

Comment: Basically (and simplified) the FIX spec says that a FIX engine should send a ResendRequest as long as the last received message sequence number is higher than the expected sequence number. Quickly browsing the spec I also did not find a "cache" mentioned. But given the fact that it is quite inefficient to re-request messages that were already received the FIX engines use a cache to buffer the messages until the gap has been filled completely.

Comment: Could you point me to this behavior in Quifix/j sources? I assume I will be able to understand the limits implied by this mecanism by reading the code.

Comment: This is done in the nextQueued() methods that QFJ as well as QuickFIX/N has. Basically it is checked on every received message if there are still queued messages until the gap has been filled. E.g. here https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/master/QuickFIXn/Session.cs#L1614

Comment: QuickFIX/n has never officially released a NuGet package.  The ones you found were made by someone else.

Comment: We may have fixed this issue in 1.9.  Please download the latest dlls and try them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems that the easiest way to solve the issue is by using SEND_REDUNDANT_RESENDREQUESTS to false. This option exist in both QuickFix/J and N and was suggested by my other party. @Grant We see that you are very active those days. Thank you so much for your work on QuickFix/n this is very helpfull.

Comment: Glad you solved it.  You should post that as an answer to this question.  (And yes, working hard to clear our PR and Issue backlog.  Working toward a 1.10!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When digging a bit more we finally found out that the real issue was my client asking again and again for the same retransmission.

For instance, if I'm 4000 sequence numbers away an I resend a retransmission message each time there is a sequence discrepency (let's say every 10 messages) I may end up asking 500 times for more than 1000+ messages in average.

This generates a high tension on server side and only makes things worse.

There is an option in QuickFIX/J which is also available in QuickFIX/N (but undocumented on this one): `SendRedundantResendRequests`. By setting it to `false` you make sure your client does not ask twice for the same retransmission. This greatly lowers the pressure on the server and eases the reconnection.

Comment: This setting is `false` by default (at least in QFJ). I certainly hope it is also `false` by default in QuickFIX/N.